# Use only WiFi connection (not cellular network) in app?

Tags: ios, xcode

My app has been rejected in the Apple app-store.

To fix this, it must use only WiFi and not cellular network connection when the user is using the application. The application uses UIWebView -- how can we go about implementing this restriction?

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: @pst: It depends on the application. I tethered my phone to my laptop recently because I didn't want to pay $15 per day for Internet access at a hotel, and blew out the data plan on my phone for the month, because Windows 7 decided to download a bunch of updates in the background.

Comment: Why was your app rejected for using cellular?  Lots of app use cellular data?  Curious because I'm going to be submitting an app that requires internet connection and I'd like to head anything off before I submit.  Were you doing something specific they objected to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [**Reachability**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) example from Apple.

With that, you can query the device about the current network status, so you can know if Wifi is available, or if a connection will need cellular network. In the last case, you may display an alert, and prevent your UIWebView to load the data.

**EDIT**

If you have imported the reachability class into your project, and added the required framework(s), here's an example. This will test for an available WiFi connection:

```
Reachability * reach;
NetworkStatus  status;

reachability = [ Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi ];
status       = [ reach currentReachabilityStatus ];

if( status == ReachableViaWiFi )
{
    /* Hurray, you've got a WiFi connection! */
}
else
{
    /* No WiFi connection - Alert the user! */
}
```

Comment: any tutorial how to implement only wifi in the app?

Comment: This is actually a tutorial. Download the sample app and try.

Comment: All you really need is the `Reachability` class, and a custom implementation of `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;` as Macmade said.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I started programming a few week ago. I imported the framework and the Reachability.h to my project. But don't know what I have to do now

Comment: thanks. I have added the framework and added the Reachability.h to my project. Is that correct? Now what I have to write to make the app use only wifi connection and not cellular data? Sorry, I'm new at this. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I don't understant it. I have just to copy and paste it? Thank you very much for your help and sorry, I'm new

Comment: Well, just try... If you want to be a good programmer, you'll need to be curious some times...

Comment: Seems that cellular data is still active